# If First flight was delayed, and couldn't catch next flight, does Pegasus airlines hold responsibility?

Tags: air-travel, transit, pegasus-airlines

I'm going from Greece to Sabiha then KSA

Both flights will be international. Is it enough to have only 1 hour and 45 minutes layover for an international flight??

If the first flight was delayed, does Pegasus airlines take responsibility and give me another flight?

Given that it's one booking all flights are from Pegasus airline

Comment: Not only do they have to accommodate you on the next available flight, but they also owe you assistance (meals, hotel of overnight stay, etc.) and possibly compensation if it’s their fault.

Answer (score 1):

This is very interesting. There is no official answer as far as I can see not even in the [Terms and Conditions](https://www.flypgs.com/en/generalrule/pdf) or the [Passenger rights](https://cdnp.flypgs.com/files/pdf/EN_yolcu_haklar__kart_.pdf), however the [Connection Problems](https://www.flypgs.com/en/write-to-us/a0j58000000NHXOAA4#sf-2) has this to say:

> Do I need to check-in again for my transit/transfer flight?
>
> If the ticket for your transit flight has just one PNR, you can follow the directions from our transfer staff and go straight to your transit flight without going through another check-in. Your baggage will be sent directly to your destination.

which should mean this is an airline which operates in the traditional manner and takes responsibility of you for the entirety of your flight. Compare to [Wizz Air](https://wizzair.com/en-gb/information-and-services/booking-information/how-to-book#/)

> Wizz Air does not operate connecting flights and cannot facilitate the transfer of passengers or their baggage to other flights (whether operated by Wizz Air or other carriers). For this reason, we cannot accept liability for any missed onward flights.

Edit: as a comment notes, EU 261 applies but that doesn't mean the airline is required to put you on the next flight... it does, however, mandate the airline to offer you a full refund and a free return to home if you are delayed more than five hours and simply they are better off if they get you to your destination instead. In practice, this means what you want because you start from the EU and have a single ticket.

Comment: Why would the age-old "if it's one reservation, don't worry" not apply? Is there a single airline which doesn't honor that?

Comment: Age old and tradition and such doesn't matter, the law and the contract does.

Comment: Case law is pretty clear than in the EU, if it’s a single booking, EU261 applies. I suppose Wizz Air will simply not sell connecting flights at all, like many of the other LCCs.

Comment: The addition to the answer blatantly misrepresents what the EU rules require. I wonder what your agenda is here ...

Comment: Let's move this discussion to a [question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/133634/4188).